# Inject style in chrome-extensions:// using Tampermonkey

Tags: tampermonkey, userscripts

What i basically want is
[image]
inject `filter:invert(1)` into the default pdf reader extension of chrome

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Dark mode pdf
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/index.html
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    GM_addStyle("embed{filter:invert(1);}");
})();
```

i tried this but it didn't work && if you press ctrl+shift+i on the pdf reader page then[image: devtools]these show rather than the one i want to edit in, to get those i need to right click on the pdf then go to inspect meaning inspecting the embed. So can anyone help with this script, or tell how to inject style in embed of extension.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think tampermonkey is allowed to alter a binary viewer extension

> JavaScript programs that can be used to modify **web** pages.

PDFs are NOT web html pages they are Application/pdf so run outside of the html, they need to "Do it Themselves" here in a FireFox extension pressing <kbd>I</kbd> I can invert the binary view of this page as HTML OR PDF, should be the same in Chrome's Foxit extension, but dont think they added that yet? You will need to alter the exe or dll.

[image]

Here too the online web page can be at a click inverted in the binary view, however, I do not recommend online web html as a good experience in a pdf viewer as Stack Overflow complains Windows app browsing is out of date (Win 11 still uses Trident), and its very slow.

[image]